# Best practice for rollbacking a multi-purpose python script

Tags: python, database, design-patterns

I'm sorry if the title is a little ambiguous. Let me explain what I mean by that : 
I have a python script that does a few things : creates a row in a MySQL table, inserts a json document to a MongoDB, Updates stuff in a local file, and some other stuff, mostly related to databases. Thing is, I want the whole operation to be atomic. Means - If anything during the process I mentioned failed, I want to rollback everything I did. I thought of implementing a rollback function for every 'create' function I have. But I'd love to hear your opinion for how to make some sort of a linked list of operations, in which if any of the nodes failed, I want to discard all the changes done in the process.
How would you design such a thing? Is there a library in Python for such things?

Comment: It really depends on what you are doing. But python sadly does not a have magic 'undo' function. You will need to undo each of the things you did manually. There may be some tricks you could do, like do your database inserts and then call commit at end of the script. That way if your script dies before the commit, changes would thrown away. There may be other tricks like waiting to call save or something. But it really depends on what you are doing.

Comment: Yeah, you should probably just use transactions on the database(s). If it's not in a database... put it in one?

Comment: kindall : yeah but what if I use multiple databases? One transaction might work, but another one won't, which makes the former transaction fail too. So that's more like a transaction for transactions

Answer (score 0):

You should implement every action to be reversible and the reverse action to be executable even if the original action has failed. Then if you have any failures, you execute every reversal.